# How to export Keepass entries as directories and files on the local filesystem

Tags: keepass

I'd like to store key files (such as SSH keys) into Keepass. To do this, I've created directories and entries. It seems that there should be an easy way to reverse the process such as when I'm deploying onto a new computer? That way the directories inside keepass can be replicated onto the local filesystem.

Comment: While Keepass presents a tree-like interface, similar to Windows Explorer, it does not have "directories"

Comment: I can't quite understand what you are trying to do. Do you just want to copy your Keepass data file from one PC to another?

Comment: You might get some help from Keepass plugins ... http://keepass.info/plugins.html

Comment: I checked the plugins, unfortunately no way to export a kdbx into actual directories and files. Although there is a way to script this via kpcli and expect.

Comment: I am afraid that I still don't understand what you are trying to do. You talk about accessing from a new PC, which you can do just by copying the data file.  I am confuse dby the talk of directories ...

Comment: Let's forget about "accessing from a new PC". I just want to automate the exporting into filesystem. Would be great if there was a FUSE adapter to kdbx. Anyway, there doesn't seem to be a way to do this atm.